# WAMP PHP says it's deprecated | =&

Tags: php, operators, wamp, deprecated

I'm using WAMP2 with PHP 5.3.4
When I use `=&` in my code it says it's deprecated. Why? Is there any alternative?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using it with objects - then it's superfluous since php 5.0, as long as objects **always** are passed by reference.

So just replace your `=&` with `=` and behaviour will not change.

Comment: @stereofrog: come on, `references passed by value` is not the thing newbies should know on very start. `passed by reference` is good enough for him now